# How to add a nested column to a 3D Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

New to Pandas, not very sure how the 3D DataFrame works. My dataframe, called `'new'` looks like this:

```
     unique    cat    numerical   
          a  b   c  d         e  f
   0      0  1   2  3         4  5
   1      0  1   2  3         4  5
```

I want to insert column `'z'` so that it ends up like this:

```
     unique       cat    numerical   
          a  b  z   c  d         e  f
   0      0  1  9   2  3         4  5
   1      0  1  9   2  3         4  5
```

I successfully made a new column after slicing out `'unique'` from my dataframe:

Doing this:

```
new_column = new.loc[:,'unique'].assign(z=pd.Series([9,9]).values)
```

Gets me this:

```
   a  b  z
0  0  1  9
1  0  1  9
```

However I have no idea how to put it back into the dataframe. I tried:

```
new['unique'] = new_column
```

But I've since found out that it just tries to replace all the values in all the rows and columns found under `'unique'`, like this:

```
new['unique'] = 'a'
```

Gets:

```
  unique    cat    numerical   
       a  b   c  d         e  f
0      a  a   2  3         4  5
1      a  a   2  3         4  5
```

And using `.loc` gets this instead:

```
  unique     cat    numerical   
       a   b   c  d         e  f
0    NaN NaN   2  3         4  5
1    NaN NaN   2  3         4  5
```

Here's my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=[[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
datatypes=np.array(['unique','unique','cat','cat','numerical','numerical'])
columnnames=np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
new = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(datatypes,columnnames)))
print('new: ')
print(new)

new_column = new.loc[:,'unique'].assign(z=pd.Series([9,9]).values)
print('\nnew column:')
print(new_column)

new.loc[:,'unique'] = new_column
print('\nattempt 1:')
print(new)

new['unique'] = new_column
print('\nattempt 2:')
print(new)
```

Comment: What does your data generating process look like? I assume you will have more than two values for z. Can it be added at the time of generating the frame in the first place?

Comment: @ako I didn't originally want to do that as I thought it would be really cumbersome and time inefficient to keep on rearranging the values in my list of data, but that was before I found out rearranging exists... Then again, being new to pandas I don't even know if I'm using a method of generating the data frame that's suitable for me.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
# Create your new multiindexed column:
new['unique','z'] = 9
# Re-order your columns in your desired order:
new = new[['unique', 'cat', 'numerical']]

>>> new
  unique       cat    numerical   
       a  b  z   c  d         e  f
0      0  1  9   2  3         4  5
1      0  1  9   2  3         4  5
```

Comment: Damn, thanks! Could've sworn I tried that already but never mind. On a separate note, looking at what @ako said, would it be faster to add all columns at the time of generating, then rearrange the table instead of rearranging after every addition of a column?

Comment: Well, if you're literally generating your data manually, then yes, it would be better to include the data then. But I assumed you wanted to find a method specifically to add in new data, in which case I thought it's not really an option to re-generate all the data...